# Objects within objects in OCaml

Tags: oop, object, ocaml

I'm trying to figure out how I can parameterize OCaml objects with other objects. Specifically I want to be able to create a `link` object which contains a forward `node` object and a backwards `node` object, and I want to be able to create a link by saying something like:

```
let link1 = new link node_behind node_ahead;;
```

Answer (score 8):

Objects are normal expressions in OCaml, so you can pass them as function and class constructor arguments. For a deeper explanation, look at the [related section](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual007.html) in OCaml manual.

So for instance, you can write:

```
class node (name : string) = object
  method name = name
end

class link (previous : node) (next : node) = object
  method previous = previous
  method next = next
end

let () =
  let n1 = new node "n1" in
  let n2 = new node "n2" in
  let l = new link n1 n2 in
  Printf.printf "'%s' -> '%s'\n" l#previous#name l#next#name
```